# Dude, where's my thread?? (or: rename a .NET thread pool thread - is it possible?)

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, multithreading

Sometimes I find myself stepping through an application in Debug mode, until I hit 'step' on some particular line and it takes way too much time doing something, eating up 100% CPU. At this point, I hit the 'Break' button and try to find what's running that's taking so long.

The problem is, this app has a hefty amount of threads running, and at the time I hit 'Break', the execution point goes to the GUI thread that's probably just doing a 'Wait'. 
I then have to hunt through the existing threads (I counted them - this time they're 37!) trying to find the one I was executing on. I'd have to look at the stack of every one of them until I find the one I was looking for.

The thread I'm running on is an async invoke, so it runs on a thread pool thread.
I'd like to give this thread a descriptive name and reset its name at the end of the operation.

The problem is, property `Thread.Name` can only be set *once*, afterwards it gives an `InvalidOperationException`.

Any suggestions?

Oh yeah, I'm running VS2005/.NET 2.0 but I'm also curious if newer versions have better ways to handle this.

Comment: Upvote just for your title!  (not really, great question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own threadstatic property

```
public class ThreadMarker:IDisposable
{
  [ThreadStatic]
  private static string __Name;

  static Dictionary<int,string> ThreadNames=new Dictionary<int,string>();

  public static Name{get{return __Name;}}

  public ThreadMarker(string name)
  {
    lock(ThreadNames){
      ThreadNames[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId]=name;
    }
    __Name=name; 
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    ThreadNames.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    __Name="Unowned";
  } 
}
```

You can even write your own wrapper that automagically wraps your action / delegate / async callback in this using statement.

```
class NamedHandler<TArg>{
  public readonly Action<TArg> Handler;

  NamedHandler(string name,Action<TArg> handler){

    Handler=arg=>{
      using(new ThreadMarker(name)){
        handler(arg);
      }
    }     
  }
}

// usage
void doStuff(string arg){
  Log("Stuf done in thread {0} ",ThreadMarker.Name);
}    

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new NamedHandler<string>("my Thread",arg=>DoStuff(arg)).Handler);
```

Then when you stop the debugger, have a look at the contents of the variable ThreadMarker.ThreadNames and you will see which managed threads are stuck in your named handlers.

Comment: How will this help with identifying the thread within the debugger?  Will it actually pick up this property instead?  The internal field used for name is "m_Name" not "__Name" and it's not thread static.

Comment: I added some code for your problem.

You will not be able to rename a thread once it's running. What you can do though is use a threadstatic marker field that you can check when you freeze your app to see which thread is running which of your handlers.